Minion is automatic running after 2 mins instead defined WakeupInterval time
I've below minion which should run after 15 mins but it is running every after 2 mins.
   {
    "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Core.MinionPolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Core",
    "WakeupInterval": "00:15:00",
    "ListToWatch": "",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Site.Commerce.Plugin.Connector.Minions.ImportMinion, Site.Commerce.Plugin.Connector",
    "ItemsPerBatch": 10,
    "SleepBetweenBatches": 500
  },


Check Sitecore Commerce database if new WakeupInterval is update or not.
If not update, then you have to run bootstrap api from Sitecore Commerce postman collection which will bootstrap all configurations to commerce database from configuration files.
